# Prevent box-shadow from appearing below an element's left/right borders?

Tags: html, css

I'm applying a box-shadow to an element with left and right borders.

I want the box shadow to stop so it doesn't appear underneath those borders.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this without too many crazy wrappers?

`<div id="button">Box-shadow, stop before the red borders!</div>`

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AHUEY/

Comment: Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dy7cq/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a pseudo element absolutely positioned relative to your target, instead of a box shadow:

```
#button {
    position: relative;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
    border-left: 10px solid red;
    border-right: 10px solid red;
}

#button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 5px;
    background: black;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4t8YY/)

Comment: Thanks. Your approach works, however I had to use a less elegant approach of just using a wrapper element because I ran out of time!

Comment: That's a bummer; but there's always next time!

Comment: It was a complicated requirement... basically a UL with 5 floating LIs each spanning 20% width (a full-width top nav menu), and each with a 10px border between them. The UL was `display: table` and LIs were `display: table-cell`. Applying a box-shadow to the LIs resulted in the shadow forming one single continuous band across the whole page width, and I wanted it to stop at the LI borders, hence my question. I don't know if your approach would have worked in that specific scenario, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `border-right` and `border-left` with `box-shadow`:

```
#button {
background: #ccc;
text-align: center;
width: 400px;
box-shadow: 10px 0 0 0 red, -10px 0 0 0 red, 0 5px 0 0 black;
}
```

[image: example]

http://jsfiddle.net/eEnpp/

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using the spread parameter of the box shadow.

Please see the working fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/prashant_11235/dkR4H/

```
#button {
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
    height: 25px;
    border-left: 10px solid red;
    border-right: 10px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px -10px black;
}
```

Comment: This was my original approach as well, but I couldn't get it to work without changing the height of the box, which I assumed wasn't acceptable.